# How do I redefine the Bootstrap's Button background using LESS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I wonder how can I redefine the Button's background using LESS. 
From [their's website](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), there's a `btn-default-bg` property, but it accepts a `color`. I want to set the background.

I can, indeed, redefine the `.btn-default` class on my LESS file, but that will result in two `.btn-default` classes being added to the bundle. I want only one.

**How can I achieve that with less?**

**PS:** [This guy](http://yago.github.io/Bootsketch/) managed to do exactly what I want, he redefined the `.btn-default` class and in the resulting bundle there was only one class. However, he was using SASS, and I don't know if it behaves differently.

Comment: That guy did exactly what you mentioned above - he just created an overriding `.btn-default` ruleset. Duplicated redundant rulesets in his output CSS are eliminated by the CSS minifying tool used in the project build setup.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks.. That makes sense. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

this is the css .btn-default of bootstrap:

```
.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
.btn-default:hover {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  border-color: #adadad;
}
.btn-default:active:hover,
.btn-default.active:hover,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:active:focus,
.btn-default.active:focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:active.focus,
.btn-default.active.focus,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  border-color: #8c8c8c;
}
.btn-default:active,
.btn-default.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default {
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-default.disabled:hover,
.btn-default[disabled]:hover,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:hover,
.btn-default.disabled:focus,
.btn-default[disabled]:focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default:focus,
.btn-default.disabled.focus,
.btn-default[disabled].focus,
fieldset[disabled] .btn-default.focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-default .badge {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

copy this code, and change the properties on your own css...

if this does not work, you can use `!important` after each property, example:

```
.btn-default{
    background: red !important;
}
```

I hope it helps you..

Answer (score -1):

I think It's the best solution.

```
.bgColor (@bg: #ff0000) {
    background-color: @bg;
}
.btn-default {
    .bgColor() !important;
}
```